# JavaFX set background is not working in my Controller

Tags: javafx, background, setbackground

I have tried to do a mouse event in my JavaFX project which is when the mouse entered the background color will change and when the mouse exited will give null, but this error just keeps coming:

```
The method setBackground(Background) in the type Region is not applicable for the arguments (Color)
```

The method in my controller class:

```
public void barcolor(MouseEvent event) {
    menubar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e ->
        menubar.setBackground(Color.WHITE)          
    );      
    menubar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e ->
        menubar.setBackground(null)         
    );      
}
```

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory? The `setBackground(...)` method expects a `Background` reference, not a `Color` reference. Off-topic (kind of): Why are you adding event handlers inside an event handler method?

Comment: Could you provide me an example of how to change the background color in this situation. About the handler don't worry about it, it's messy at the moment

Comment: Just read the [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html) and create an appropriate `Background` object.

Comment: Unrelated to your question.  I don't know the context of this call, but adding mouse event handlers in response to mouse events seems unusual and potentially error prone to me. Normally, mouse event handlers will be added to graphic items at creation time, not in response to other mouse events.  Otherwise, you could end up creating and adding multiple handlers for the same events, which you usually don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Background mouseOverBackground = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("WHITE"),  5, 15));


public void barcolor(MouseEvent event) {
    menubar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e ->
        menubar.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("WHITE"),  5, 15)))          
    );      
    menubar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e ->
        menubar.setBackground(null)         
    );      
}
```

You need to make sure that you are passing the right arguments. The setBackground() command only accepts BackgroundFill() and BackgroundImage() as arguments. Either save the background to a variable, or insert it directly into the function.